# Is it a security risk to let ssh-agent always use the same socket?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I use `ssh-agent` as a wrapper program for `startx`. Is it a security risk, to use always the same socket file?

`ssh-agent -a /tmp/xyz123 startx`

`-a` specifies the socket bind address. If not specified, it would be a random filename.

I'd like to use a fix socket filename because I want to specify `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/xyz123` in my crontab file. Otherwise cronjobs that use SSH fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, using `/tmp` is a minor security risk. Using the same file name is not a problem because even if you change it every time, it'll be easy to find.

Put the socket in a directory readable only by the user itself.

E.g. On many recent distributions, the socket file is always `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` where 1000 is the user's id.

Comment: Since the socket is already readable only by the user isn't hiding it just a form of "security by obscurity"? In other words hardly more secure than current state?

Comment: It is not "security by obscurity". Even if do you know the file location (as in my example), you have to break the dir permissions before you can start to break the file permissions.

Comment: P.S. Yes, I am a little bit paranoid ;-)

Comment: I'm talking about the hiding as independent from the normal protections. IOW, the additional security is "SbyO" not the overall security. A downside is the potential to give a user a false sense of being more protected than they actually are. But if you know this than s'okay...if you're in the "more is better" camp I won't judge you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The socket has the same protection as the contents of your `~/.ssh` dir: file permissions restrict other users from accessing it. One typically operates under the assumption that this is secure. If one can't operate under that assumption then there are countless other vulnerabilities in the system so worrying about a socket is not a good use of worry time. :)

From an external standpoint, all communications are encrypted (of course!) so I don't see how using the same socket poses any problems when looking from the outside in.

I'd say that ensuring the name always changes adds a tiny increment of additional security (by obscurity)...not to the point that I'd go out of my way to do it or start thinking that I'd stopped all the black hats in their tracks.